# Trying to transform XML with XSLT, but the output line breaks

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Trying to transform XML with XSLT, but the output line breaks.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="1.0">

 <xsl:template match="/" >
    <data>
     <content>
            <xsl:for-each select="//t[@pos='ADV' or @pos='ADJD' or @pos='ADJA' or @pos='NE' or 
                                      @pos='NN' or @pos='VMFIN' or @pos='VVINF' or @pos='VAFIN' or 
                                      @pos='VVPP' or @pos='VVFIN']">
                <xsl:sort select="@word"/>
                    <token>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@word"/>
                        (<xsl:value-of select="@lemma"/>;
                        <xsl:value-of select="@pos"/>;
                        <xsl:value-of select="@morph"/>)
                    </token>
            </xsl:for-each>    
    </content>
   </data>
 </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Im getting this as output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data><content><token>Aktivitäten
                        (Aktivität;
                        NN;
                        Acc.Pl.Fem)
                    </token><token>Bank
                        (Bank;
                        NN;
                        Dat.Sg.Fem)
                    </token><token>Behörden
                        (Behörde;
                        NN;
                        Dat.Pl.Fem)
                    </token>
```

Im trying to replicate this output result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
 <content>
   <token>Aktivitäten(Aktivität;NN;Acc.Pl.Fem)</token>
   <token>Bank(Bank;NN;Dat.Sg.Fem)</token>
   <token>Behörden(Behörde;NN;Dat.Pl.Fem)</token>
   etc...
```

I'm new to XSLT thanks for any assistance

Comment: Well written first question. Welcome to StackOverflow buddy!

Comment: Sample XML input would complete the [mcve] and make it a great first question.   Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The normally insignificant white space is made significant when abutted with other literal text such as `(`, `;`, and `)`.

If you wrap each of those strings (characters) in `xsl:text`,

```
                    <xsl:value-of select="@word"/>
                    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@lemma"/>
                    <xsl:text>;<xsl:text>
                    ...
```

you'll get your desired XML output.

---

Another way [thanks to [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)] to eliminate the undesired white space is to concatenate the string values in a single `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@word, '(', @lemma, ';', @pos, ';', @morph, ')')" />
```

Comment: @sivert You can also use the `concat()` function like this: `<xsl:value-of select="concat(@word, '(', @lemma, '...')" />`

Comment: @Tomalak: Agreed, for this simple case, I should have mentioned your good idea too.  Answer updated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the beginning of your output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data><content><token>
```

It is the result of default output `indent` attribute set to `no`.
The reason of this setting is that if the output XML is not to be read by
a human, its processing runs quicker when it contains no additional spaces
and newlines.

The reason that your `token` output tag has "additional" newlines and spaces
is that they are actually included in your script.

Look at the following fragment of your script:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@word"/>
(<xsl:value-of select="@lemma"/>;
```

After `<xsl:value-of select="@word"/>` your script contains a text token,
containing:

- a newline,
- some spaces,
- and finally `(` - the only thing which actually should be printed.

To get the result you want, make 2 changes:

- After `xsl:stylesheet` opening tag, add `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`.
- Change the content of `token` to a single `xsl:value-of` with `select="concat(...)"`
  with all stuff to print as arguments of `concat` function.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/aiwQ3T

Comment: The suggestion to add `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` is new (+1), but the rest really just repeats what's already been said.